# How do I install libraries for <stropts.h>?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, debian

I am running Kali-Linux (debian+gnome). When I compile I get compilation error:

```cpp
cc -Wall -g   -c -o frag.o frag.c
frag.c:7:10: fatal error: stropts.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <stropts.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: frag.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing and what should I install?
I tried installing glibc-sources but still it didn't work out.

Comment: On Linux? You don't. It never supported STREAMS.

Comment: Older versions of debian supported stropts.h, it appears this support was removed in the new bullseye version, as even debian buster gcc compiles fine with an #include <stropts.h> statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by the other answer, this library is not used on Linux. Since this came up when trying to compile an application on Linux, it's possible an `#if` was not set correctly.

As a workaround, look at the source code to see what the `#if` surrounding the `#include` is, and set that to false when compiling.

For example, if the code looked like:

```c
#if HAVE_STROPTS_H
#include <stropts.h>
#endif
```

And if you are using cmake or gcc, run them with `-DHAVE_STROPTS_H=0`.

Answer (score 5):

`stropts.h` is part of the Posix STREAMS extension, which Linux never supported. (Since 2008, it has also been marked as obsolescent by Posix, so it may be removed in some future standard revision.)

There have been third-party implementations of STREAMS for Linux, but I don't kniw if any of them are still supported. One which is used by Linux-based telephony apps is contained in [openss7](http://www.openss7.org).

Answer (score 0):

Another reason not yet mentioned might be the confusion manual introduces. If you need to use `ioctl()` call, the quickest way to find out the header to include might be pulling up a `man ioctl`. Well, it turns out there are 2 different manual pages for `ioctl()`, and having both on the system will result in this misleading and wrong suggestion *([accessible directly as `man 3 ioctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ioctl))* of including the `stropts.h`.

More likely you actually need a `sys/ioctl.h`, [described in `man 2 ioctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl):

```c
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```